# Need help to design MySQL Query with conditionals

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to design a query which count the number of occurrences of a string on a field.

Like this

```
SELECT     COUNT(*) AS totalOccurrences,
           SUM(if(t1.field = 'foo', 1, 0)) AS foo,
           SUM(if(t1.field = 'faa', 1, 0)) AS faa

FROM TABLE t1
```

This query runs fine but, now I need to count the occurrences of a field of another table related with the field of the first table.

I've tried this but it doesn't works fine. I think that count each occurrence of the second table and only need to count if one occurrence is founded.

This is my current test

```
SELECT     COUNT(*) AS totalOccurrences,
           SUM(if(t1.field = 'foo', 1, 0)) AS foo,
           SUM(if(t1.field = 'foo' and t2.field != '', 1, 0) as subocuFoo,
           SUM(if(t1.field = 'faa', 1, 0)) AS faa,
           SUM(if(t1.field = 'faa' and t2.field != '', 1, 0) as subocuFaa
FROM       TABLE t1 
inner join TABLE2 t2
on         t1.field2 = t2.field2 
inner join (select subfield, subfield2 from SUBTABLE where subfield2 LIKE '%fii%') ST
ON         t2.field2=t3.subfield
```

How can count on `SUM(if(t1.field = 'foo' and t2.field != '', 1, 0)` the ocurrences only one time of all occurrences of the second table?

Sorry if I not explain correctly

**EDIT1:**

Sample input

**TABLE t1**

```
  *field   field2*
    foo      1
    faa      2
```

**TABLE t2**

```
  *field field2   fieldst*
   text    1         1
   text    1         2
```

**SUBTABLE ST**

```
  *fieldst   subfield2*
     1          mii
     2          fii
```

**Sample desired output**

```
  *totalOccurrences   foo    suboccuFoo     faa    suboccuFaa*
         2             1         1           1         0
```

Comment: Could you please provide sample input and desired output?

Comment: I've added a sample output and input, i hope it helps :(

Comment: Some more questions: 1) are you allowed to change the tables' structure? 2) The result of 2 in `totalOccurences` is due to the table having 2 rows or due to the table having 2 distinct values of some of its fields? 3) Are values different from 'foo' and 'faa' allowed in Table1?